# Geoserver layer pyramids in googledrive

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, centos, image-pyramids, google-drive

is it possible to create pyramid from large rasters and add them with folders to google drive and mount google drive as local drive to geoserver ? i tried to search in internet to find about it and found syncdrive and grive for linux.Can these tools be used in linux servers(like centos,fedora,...)?
geoserver rest api has this capability to read raster pyramids from google drive?

Comment: I wonder if this brand new Amazon S3 BlobStore could suit you http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/gwc-s3/index.html.

Comment: geoserver limits to this choice?we can not use other cloud hosts for geoserver?

Comment: S3 BlobStore is a community module. Someone needed to use S3 and wrote a module for that and decided kindly to publish it for others as open source but it is not maintained by the GeoServer project. I believe that the only blob store that is officially supported for GeoWebCache is to use local disk.

Comment: so it is geoserver deficiency and we must write appropraite plugin?

Comment: In GeoServer the tiling stuff is handled by an integrated GeoWebCache so I would ask the GeoWebCache developers first. They for sure know if Google drive can already be used with some undocumented way and also guide you if you need to write your own plugin.

Comment: That isn't how it works - you do your own work. In any case, you'll likely get pretty poor performance from a high-latency store.

Comment: You could do this - using those tools your google drive just looks like a slow local disk. But why would you want to?

Comment: so how and with what tools i do it for large raster pyramids?

Answer (score 1):

alternative to googledrive is aws bucket!
this tutorial:
[S3 Bucket Mounting as a File System in Linux using S3fs and S3fuse](http://walkintocloud.com/2014/01/s3-bucket-mounting-as-a-file-system-in-linux-using-s3fs-and-s3fuse/)

this is good,easy management,low price an fast especially for geoserver tiles([geoserver](http://geoserver.org))